# Node.js server randomly throws EAI_AGAIN

Tags: node.js

My Node.js server sometimes throws an EAI_AGAIN error, and I don't know why. I have multiple, completly different Node apps running on my Linux server and when this error throws, it mostly does on all apps the same time. The error occurrs not regularly, this week once and 2-3 times in the last month.

On this [Linux manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo), I can see that EAI_AGAIN means the following:

> The name server returned a temporary failure indication. Try again later.

Is there anything wrong on my Linux server or in my Node apps? Or should I just ignore this error? Maybe it's an error that sometimes just occurrs like a timeout and I can't do anything against it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: getaddrinfo EAI\_AGAIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182121/error-getaddrinfo-eai-again)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found a hint to your question in the following link: http://www.codingdefined.com/2015/06/nodejs-error-errno-eaiagain.html

I'm not sure what can be done about the error itself other than that it shouldn't lock/close/mess-up your node.js services. If it does break your Node apps then I have misunderstood your question. But if I am to believe the information in the link it is just one of those things that can happen. 
If you can, catch the error, wait a few moments (moments being minutes or seconds, depending on what your Node apps do) and retry whatever it was you were trying to do.