# What's the cause of the error 'getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, dns, shopify

My server threw this today, which is a Node.js error I've never seen before:

```
Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN my-store.myshopify.com:443
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at errnoException (dns.js:32:15)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:78:26)
```

I'm wondering if this is related to the DynDns DDOS attack which affected Shopify and many other services today. [Here's an article about that.](http://thenextweb.com/security/2016/10/21/massive-ddos-attack-dyn-dns-causing-havoc-online/)

My main question is what does `dns.js` do? What part of node is it a part of? How can I recreate this error with a different domain?

Comment: Got this error because my GHA did not have Elasticsearch service setup

Comment: Did somebody consider to update the systemd service files of docker and/or containerd? Like adding `After=nss-lookup.target` maybe?

Answer (score 249, accepted):

EAI_AGAIN is a DNS lookup timed out error, means it is a network connectivity error or proxy related error.

> My main question is what does dns.js do?

- The dns.js is there for node to get ip address of the domain(in brief).

Some more info:
http://www.codingdefined.com/2015/06/nodejs-error-errno-eaiagain.html

Answer (score 213):

If you get this error with Firebase Cloud Functions, this is due to the limitations of the free tier (*outbound networking only allowed to Google services*).

Upgrade to the **Flame** or **Blaze** plans for it to work.

[image]

Comment: that's right, just upgraded to pay per use blaze plan for zero cost (this carry-forward free tier data from spark)

Comment: Can you @NullPointer, elaborate the solution, i still getting errors ` Error: could not handle the request`

Comment: I have same issue and have upgraded to Blaze account but still the problem is same. I am trying using postman.

Comment: For some reason I've had this when trying access my credentials for SMTP via `process.env.SOMETHING`, even with the `Blaze` enabled.

Comment: In my case I was already on Blaze plan, just that my card had expired.

Answer (score 57):

If you get this error **from within a docker container**, e.g. when running `npm install` inside of an alpine container, the cause could be that the network changed since the container was started.

To solve this, just **stop and restart the container**

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up
```

Source: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32106#issuecomment-578725551

Comment: I have a suspected issue where the network is reset on the host, and then the containers seem to have DNS errors thereafter.  Is there some way to configure the containers to survive this *without* stopping them?

Comment: I tried `docker-compose up -d --build` and it wasn't fixed. So I guess `docker-compose down` then `docker-compose up` is the only solution

Comment: Restarting the specific docker container solved my issue as well. I think the problem is that the docker image is starting faster than my OS network is ready. Causing issues in resolving/DNS. I think containerd.service or docker.service should `Requires=network-online.target`. Or: `After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target` OR even better maybe: `After=nss-lookup.target`

Comment: Exactly what was happening in my case, thanks!

Answer (score 30):

For those who perform thousand or millions of requests per day, and need a solution to this issue:

It's quite normal to get `getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN` errors when performing a lot of requests on your server. Node.js itself doesn't perform any DNS caching, it delegates everything DNS related to the OS.

You need to have in mind that every http/https request performs a DNS lookup, this can become quite expensive, to avoid this bottleneck and `getaddrinfo` errors, you can implement a DNS cache.

[`http.request`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httprequestoptions-callback) (and https) accepts a `lookup` property which defaults to [`dns.lookup()`](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dnslookuphostname-options-callback)

```
http.get('http://example.com', { lookup: yourLookupImplementation }, response => {
    // do something here with response
});
```

I **strongly recommend** to use an already tested module, instead of writing a DNS cache yourself, since you'll have to handle TTL correctly, among other things to avoid hard to track bugs.

I personally use [`cacheable-lookup`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cacheable-lookup) which is the one that [`got`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) uses (see [`dnsCache`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/blob/main/documentation/2-options.md#dnscache) option).

You can use it on specific requests

```
const http = require('http');
const CacheableLookup = require('cacheable-lookup');

const cacheable = new CacheableLookup();

http.get('http://example.com', {lookup: cacheable.lookup}, response => {
    // Handle the response here
});
```

or globally

```
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const CacheableLookup = require('cacheable-lookup');

const cacheable = new CacheableLookup();

cacheable.install(http.globalAgent);
cacheable.install(https.globalAgent);
```

NOTE: have in mind that if a request is not performed through Node.js `http/https` module, using `.install` on the global agent won't have any effect on said request, for example requests made using [`undici`](https://undici.nodejs.org)

---

If you're using `undici` you can use [`undici.setGlobalDispatcher()`](https://undici.nodejs.org/#/?id=undicisetglobaldispatcherdispatcher)

```
import { Agent, setGlobalDispatcher } from 'undici';
import CacheableLookup from 'cacheable-lookup';

const cacheable = new CacheableLookup();

const agent = new Agent({
    connect: {
        lookup: cacheable.lookup
    }
});

setGlobalDispatcher(agent);

await fetch('https://google.com'); // will be cached
```

If you don't want to set it for all requests, you could do the following:

```
await fetch('https://google.com', {
    dispatcher: agent
});
```

Comment: Best answer for me. Should be marked as the official response.

Answer (score 26):

As [xerq's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40182520/123671) explains, this is a DNS timeout issue.

I wanted to contribute another possible answer for those of you using **Windows Subsystem for Linux - there are some cases where something seems to be askew in the client OS after Windows resumes from sleep**. Restarting the host OS will fix these issues (it's also likely restarting the WSL service will do the same).

Answer (score 6):

I was having this issue on docker-compose. Turns out I forgot to add my custom isolated named network to my service which couldn't be found.

TLDR; Make sure, in your compose file, you have your [custom-networks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks) defined on both services that need to talk to each other.

My error looked like this: `Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN minio-service`. The error was coming from my server's backend when making a call to the `minio-service` using the `minio-service` hostname. This tells me that `minio-service`'s running service, was not reachable by my `server`'s running service. The way I was able to fix this issue is I changed the minio-service in my docker-compose from this:

- **docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "3.8"

# ...

services:
  server:
    # ...
    networks:
      my-network:
    # ...
  minio-service:
    # ... (missing networks: section)

# ...

networks:
  my-network:
```

To include my custom isolated named network, like this:

- **docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "3.8"

# ...

services:
  server:
    # ...
    networks:
      my-network:
    # ...
  minio-service:
    # ...   
    networks:
      my-network:
    # ...

# ...

networks:
  my-network:
```

[More details on docker-compose networking can be found here.](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Comment: I have this issue when going outside the network (=internet). However, often only during reboots. Manually restarting the docker container fixes the problem. I think Docker is starting my containers faster than my network/DNS resolver is ready to handle the requests. I think `After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target` are missing from containerd.service or docker.service systemd configs. Or `After=nss-lookup.target` should be added

Answer (score 5):

The OP's error specifies a host (`my-store.myshopify.com`).
The error I encountered is the same in all respects except that no domain is specified.

My solution may help others who are drawn here by the title "Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN"

I encountered the error when trying to serve a NodeJs & VueJs app from a different VM from where the code was developed originally.

The file `vue.config.js` read :

```
 module.exports = {
   devServer: {
     host: 'tstvm01',
     port: 3030,
   },
 };
```

When served on the original machine the start up output is :

```
App running at:
- Local:   http://tstvm01:3030/ 
- Network: http://tstvm01:3030/
```

Using the same settings on a VM `tstvm07` got me a very similar error to the one the OP describes:

```
 INFO  Starting development server...
 10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 activeevents.js:183                              
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at errnoException (dns.js:55:15)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
```

If it ain't already obvious, changing `vue.config.js` to read ...

```
 module.exports = {
   devServer: {
     host: 'tstvm07',
     port: 3030,
   },
 };
```

... solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I started getting this error (different stack trace though) after making a trivial update to my GraphQL API application that is operated inside a docker container. For whatever reason, the container was having difficulty resolving a back-end service being used by the API.

After poking around to see if some change had been made in the docker base image I was building from (node:13-alpine, incidentally), I decided to try the oldest computer science trick of rebooting... I stopped and started the docker container and all went back to normal.

Clearly, this isn't a meaningful solution to the underlying problem - I am merely posting this since it did clear up the issue for me without going too deep down rabbit holes.

Answer (score 3):

This is the issue related to hosts file setup.
Add the following line to your hosts file
In Ubuntu:   /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

In windows:  c:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

Comment: This should be setup by default on Ubuntu systems

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was the docker networks ip allocation range, see [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/936255) for details

Answer (score 2):

In my case, connected to VPN, the error happens when running Ubuntu from inside Windows Terminal but doesn't happen when opening Ubuntu directly from Windows (not from inside the Windows Terminal)

[image]

Comment: hey man, thanks for sharing. I have the same issue here. But I didn't understood how you resolved this. Can you say what do you mean with "opening Ubuntu directly from Windows"? Thank you.

Comment: added screenshot, Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, from Windows menu. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have Windows 11 updated and I don't have this Bash option for Ubuntu. Sad.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error after I recently added a new `network` to my docker-compose file.

I initially had these services:

```yaml
services:
  frontend:
    depends_on:
      - backend
    ports:
      - 3005:3000
  
  backend:
    ports:
      - 8005:8000
```

I decided to add a new network which hosts other services I wanted my `frontend` service to have access to, so I did this:

```yaml
networks:
  moar:
    name: moar-network
    attachable: true

services:
  frontend:
    networks:
      - moar
    depends_on:
      - backend
    ports:
      - 3005:3000
  
  backend:
    ports:
      - 8005:8000
```

Unfortunately, the above made it so that my `frontend` service was no longer visible on the `default` network, and only visible in the `moar` network. This meant that the `frontend` service could no longer proxy requests to `backend`, therefore I was getting errors like:

> Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:3005/graphql/

The solution is to add the `default` network to the `frontend` service's network list, like so:

```yaml
networks:
  moar:
    name: moar-network
    attachable: true

services:
  frontend:
    networks:
      - moar
      - default # here
    depends_on:
      - backend
    ports:
      - 3005:3000
  
  backend:
    ports:
      - 8005:8000
```

Now we're peachy!

---

One last thing, if you want to see which services are running within a given network, you can use the `docker network inspect <network_name>` command to do so. This is what helped me discover that the `frontend` service was not part of the default network anymore.

Answer (score 1):

@xerq pointed correctly, here's some more reference
http://www.codingdefined.com/2015/06/nodejs-error-errno-eaiagain.html

i got the same error, i solved it by updating "hosts" file present under this location in windows os

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem with AWS and Serverless. I tried with `eu-central-1` region and it didn't work so I had to change it to `us-east-2` for the example.

Answer (score -3):

**Enabled Blaze and it still doesn't work?**

Most probably you need to set `.env` from the right path, `require('dotenv').config({ path: __dirname + './../.env' });` [won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65080783/11127383) (or any other path). Simply put the `.env` file in the `functions` directory, from which you deploy to `Firebase`.