# Unable to install ionic using npm

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-code, npm-install

I am unable to install ionic using npm. Found the similar questions but there is no solution.

`C:\Users\xxxx>npm install -g ionic`

I am getting npm error.
[image]

It would be great if you provide the solution early.
Thankyou.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182121/error-getaddrinfo-eai-again

Comment: also https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/15059

Comment: Hi Suraj, do we need any admin rights for the machine to get install? I am getting same error while installing the latest npm.

Comment: you probably have some network issues.. is your system behind some proxy?

Comment: Yes suraj... how can I resolve if that's the case?

Comment: you will  have to check with the network admin or proxy to see if it is blocking npm registry url..check the answers in the SO link