# no internet inside docker on VM

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am running mode-red module of nodejs with docker-compose in following way:

```
version: "3"
services:
    node-red:
        build: node-red/.
        container_name: mynodered
        network_mode: "host"
        volumes:
         - $PWD/data/node:/data
        ports:
         - "1880:1880"
```

I have placed the following docker file in folder `node-red`:

```
FROM nodered/node-red-docker:v8
RUN npm i -S basic-auth bcryptjs body-parser cheerio clone cookie cookie-parser cors cron express express-session follow-redirects fs-extra fs.notify hash-sum i18next is-utf8 js-yaml json-stringify-safe jsonata media-typer memorystore mqtt multer mustache node-red-contrib-cloudera node-red-contrib-confluent node-red-contrib-ksql node-red-contrib-python-function node-red-contrib-rdkafka node-red-contrib-s3 node-red-node-email node-red-node-feedparser node-red-node-rbe node-red-node-twitter nopt oauth2orize on-headers passport passport-http-bearer passport-oauth2-client-password raw-body semver sentiment uglify-js when ws xml2js && npm i -D chromedriver grunt grunt-chmod grunt-cli grunt-concurrent grunt-contrib-clean grunt-contrib-compress grunt-contrib-concat grunt-contrib-copy grunt-contrib-jshint grunt-contrib-uglify grunt-contrib-watch grunt-jsonlint grunt-mocha-istanbul grunt-nodemon grunt-sass grunt-simple-mocha grunt-webdriver istanbul mocha should sinon supertest wdio-chromedriver-service wdio-mocha-framework wdio-spec-reporter webdriverio && npm i -O bcrypt
```

When i am building image **explicitly** from this docker file in following way,its working **fine**

`docker build --network host -t dvnode .`

But when i am using docker-compose,it gives following error:

```
docker-compose up
Building node-red
Step 1/2 : FROM nodered/node-red-docker:v8
 ---> 8d6fdff59c2c
Step 2/2 : RUN npm i -S basic-auth bcryptjs body-parser cheerio clone cookie cookie-parser cors cron express express-session follow-redirects fs-extra fs.notify hash-sum i18next is-utf8 js-yaml json-stringify-safe jsonata media-typer memorystore mqtt multer mustache node-red-contrib-cloudera node-red-contrib-confluent node-red-contrib-ksql node-red-contrib-python-function node-red-contrib-rdkafka node-red-contrib-s3 node-red-node-email node-red-node-feedparser node-red-node-rbe node-red-node-twitter nopt oauth2orize on-headers passport passport-http-bearer passport-oauth2-client-password raw-body semver sentiment uglify-js when ws xml2js && npm i -D chromedriver grunt grunt-chmod grunt-cli grunt-concurrent grunt-contrib-clean grunt-contrib-compress grunt-contrib-concat grunt-contrib-copy grunt-contrib-jshint grunt-contrib-uglify grunt-contrib-watch grunt-jsonlint grunt-mocha-istanbul grunt-nodemon grunt-sass grunt-simple-mocha grunt-webdriver istanbul mocha should sinon supertest wdio-chromedriver-service wdio-mocha-framework wdio-spec-reporter webdriverio && npm i -O bcrypt
 ---> Running in a69e76805cc1
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EAI_AGAIN: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/basic-auth failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
npm WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/node-red-contrib-cloudera failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /usr/src/node-red/.npm/_logs/2018-05-03T08_10_08_489Z-debug.log
ERROR: Service 'node-red' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm i -S basic-auth bcryptjs body-parser cheerio clone cookie cookie-parser cors cron express express-session follow-redirects fs-extra fs.notify hash-sum i18next is-utf8 js-yaml json-stringify-safe jsonata media-typer memorystore mqtt multer mustache node-red-contrib-cloudera node-red-contrib-confluent node-red-contrib-ksql node-red-contrib-python-function node-red-contrib-rdkafka node-red-contrib-s3 node-red-node-email node-red-node-feedparser node-red-node-rbe node-red-node-twitter nopt oauth2orize on-headers passport passport-http-bearer passport-oauth2-client-password raw-body semver sentiment uglify-js when ws xml2js && npm i -D chromedriver grunt grunt-chmod grunt-cli grunt-concurrent grunt-contrib-clean grunt-contrib-compress grunt-contrib-concat grunt-contrib-copy grunt-contrib-jshint grunt-contrib-uglify grunt-contrib-watch grunt-jsonlint grunt-mocha-istanbul grunt-nodemon grunt-sass grunt-simple-mocha grunt-webdriver istanbul mocha should sinon supertest wdio-chromedriver-service wdio-mocha-framework wdio-spec-reporter webdriverio && npm i -O bcrypt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: The error implies that the docker container failed to look up the ip address of a hostname via DNS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182121/error-getaddrinfo-eai-again

Comment: @hardillb I agree,then issue should also come on running explicitly in network_mode as mentioned above.

Comment: Docker compose features on container-level (not building images), so I think the `network_mode` is consumed by `docker run` which is implicitly called when you run `docker-compose up`. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings.

Comment: @momocow, I tried `docker-compose build` too,Same error

Comment: I mean any configuration you write in a `docker-compose.yml` is consumed by `docker run` since docker compose features especially on **container level**. I haven't found yet any equivalence config to achieve this in a `docker-compose.yml` for a building routine.

Comment: It seems to be an error with DNS while building an image. To work around it, how about manually adding NPM registry host to `/etc/hosts` in the Dockerfile? `RUN echo "151.101.52.162 registry.npmjs.org" >> /etc/hosts`

Comment: @momocow It is giving issue `FROM nodered/node-red-docker:v8
---> 8d6fdff59c2c
Step 2/3 : RUN echo "151.101.52.162 registry.npmjs.org" >> /etc/hosts
 ---> Running in 477a467f6fd2
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create /etc/hosts: Permission denied
ERROR: Service 'node-red' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c echo "151.101.52.162 registry.npmjs.org" >> /etc/hosts' returned a non-zero code: 2`

Comment: `cannot create /etc/hosts: Permission denied`. The base image, i.e. [`node-red-docker`](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-docker/blob/master/latest/Dockerfile), changes the user to a non-root user without `sudo` privilege; so we have to try another way.

Comment: You may change npm configuration to tell it use the IP (151.101.52.162) instead of the domain name (registry.npmjs.org), (See [official npm doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#registry)). The following workaround uses environment variable to change npm config (there's other ways mentioned in the official doc). Add this line before you call `npm install`: `ENV NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY=https://151.101.52.162`.

Comment: @momocow,it was issue of DNS lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comment by hardlib,it was actually the issue of DNS lookup and as per [link](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/5920),I was able to solve the same issue.Thus,reiterating those steps to avoid further confusion:

1)Find the DNS pertaining to your system:

```
nmcli device show <interface-name> | grep IP4.DNS
```

where interface-name is the name found by by `ifconfig`.

2)Edit the `docker.service` file kept in `/lib/systemd/system` and replacing the `ExecStart` line in following manner and save:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --dns <dns-id> --dns <dns-id> -H fd://
```

where `dns-id` is the value found from above step.

3)Restart the service

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```