# Not able to install appium - npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN

Tags: node.js, npm, appium, npm-install

I have installed Node.js and when I run the command Node -v it gave me exact version and then I ran npm -v, it replied back with the version.
But when I try to install appium using the command "npm install appium" I have got

> npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN npm ERR! request to
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/appium failed, reason: getaddrinfo
>   EAI_AGAIN my.proxyserver.com:8080

can some one tell me why this is happening ?

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16661

Answer (score 1):

Connect to Direct Internet like Mobile hotspot or WiFi and try again.

npm install usually fails with corporate proxy.

Comment: Am using my home WiFi network, but then it is failing

Comment: > npm config rm proxy &  > npm config rm https-proxy   --tried removing npm proxy ?

Comment: From similar questions, i can suggest:
1. Also try reinstalling nodeJs or try > npm install npm@latest
2. Clear npm proxys
> npm config rm proxy 
> npm config rm https-proxy
3. Check your DNS. Or give a try with Google DNS

Comment: I tried on both (mobile hotspot and other WiFi network) but it didn't give me the expected result

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to add the -g parameter (it was not removing my proxy settings without it).  I -finally- got Appium to install properly by bypassing the corporate firewall thanks to your tip, thanks!  Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Microsoft page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this error translates to "A temporary failure in name resolution occurred". Therefore, I suppose you can just try again later. Or, depending on your version of Windows, try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47573024/4351430). I just tried installing this npm package and it works normally on my Windows 10 box.

Comment: My network is not enabled with proxy, why is it asking to set proxy each time i run the npm install -g appium command?