# Why does `npm install` hang when retrieving things from registry.npmjs.org?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I'm trying to intall NPM (`npm install`) and it just seems to hang when retrieving things from registry.npmjs.org/, eg: `registry.npmjs.org/babel-jest`. If I paste the URL into my browser, it seems to load fine. I can `curl www.google.com` fine too, so I doubt it's a proxy thing (can also clone from Github too).

Also, if I restart the install it will hang again but on a different registry.npmjs.org/ file each time.

Why is this and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: please define "hang".  Does it end up installing eventually, or does it just sit there until you end the process?  When you do curl it isnt downloading and installing all the packages for all subprocess like it is in NPM.  Essentially if it is trying to install the particular app, it runs through the dependancies, and recursively downloads them.  That way you have an infolder node_modules folder which contains everything you need for the app to run.

Comment: The installation process pauses, then produces the error:

npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN

Comment: That sounds more like a network or proxy error.  Sounds similar to the following.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182121/error-getaddrinfo-eai-again