# The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: node.js, docker

I am new to `docker` and for my learning purpose I followed [the official nodejs docker instructons](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/) and followed the instructions but it keeps throwing error on the same command.

Tried Reinstalling the whole `docker` as mentioned in the Official repository installation for Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic beaver for arch `amd64` 64 bit but still getting the same error.

*(`sudo` permissions has already been granted to `npm` and `docker`. Running `docker` and `npm` without `sudo`*
* running `npm install` works fine using in the terminal

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**ERROR**

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  19.46kB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:8
---> 55791187f71c
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
---> Using cache
---> 440112b72584
Step 3/7 : COPY package*.json ./
---> Using cache
---> 956513348aa7
Step 4/7 : RUN npm install
---> Running in dbbf0bc0d749
npm WARN hello@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/array-flatten/-/array- 
flatten-1.1.1.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN 
registry.npmjs.org:443

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-08-27T20_59_09_800Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

**Docker version and info**

```
Client:
 Version:           18.06.1-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        e68fc7a
 Built:             Tue Aug 21 17:24:51 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
Server:
 Engine:
 Version:          18.06.1-ce
 API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:       go1.10.3
 Git commit:       e68fc7a
 Built:            Tue Aug 21 17:23:15 2018
 OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
 Experimental:     false
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: getaddrinfo EAI\_AGAIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182121/error-getaddrinfo-eai-again)

Comment: I don't think this is Docker-specific - it is just a Node DNS/connectivity error. Are you behind a company firewall or proxy? [See this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=node+reason%3A+getaddrinfo+EAI_AGAIN&ia=qa).

Comment: @halfer if it would be a proxy issue then my `npm` would have the same problem running outside the `dockerfile` . currently I can run `npm` commands with ease outside the `dockerfile` via terminal

Comment: I don't know that to be the case. I've not done it myself, but Docker can be [independently configured to use a proxy](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/).

Answer (score 5):

Had this error when with this line `From node:alpine` You may need to pull from a more recent image. I currently run node 14.x.x so I just had to pull node version 14-apline. So my first line was `FROM node:14-alpine` and that did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here, apparently the `COPY package*.json ./` command didn't working fine.

I solved this copying the files before install the NPM dependencies:

```
FROM node:8.15.1-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm --verbose install
RUN npm run build
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add --force in the command.

RUN npm install --force

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue with my linux docker setup, when installing `node-sass` inside my Node.js container. It turned out that the container/ docker ran out of memory during the installation. Increasing the memory, assigned to docker, fixed the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was an error in package.json thats is why did not worked and threw same error.