# getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN account-d.docusign.com account-d.docusign.com:443

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I am using superagent to hit the docusign API with code received on the response of concent

```
const respo = await superagent
    .post('https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token')
    .set('Authorization', `${auth}`)
    .send({
        grant_type: 'authorization_code', 
        code: '.........'
    })
```

> err :  { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN account-d.docusign.com account-d.docusign.com:443
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
>     errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
>     code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
>     syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
>     hostname: 'account-d.docusign.com',
>     host: 'account-d.docusign.com',
>     port: 443,
>     response: undefined }

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182121/error-getaddrinfo-eai-again) 
"EAI_AGAIN is a DNS lookup timed out error, means it is a network connectivity error or proxy related error."

You may want to check if you have a proxy/firewall or other issues on the box making the API calls. This is a networking issue you need to fix that has nothing to do with DocuSign directly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestion. But it was because I was not sending proper authentication. 
I did use curl though for this :

```
    curl
        .setHeaders([
            `Authorization: Basic ${auth}`,
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ])
        .setBody({
            grant_type: "authorization_code",
            code: code
        })
        .post("https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token")
        .then(({ statusCode, body, headers }) => {})
        .catch(e => {});
```