# While creating build on Docker gives error

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I have completed my project in node.js.

Node version is : v16.13.0

NPM version is : 8.1.0

when client create build using Docker it gives below error

```
160 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.foreach/-/lodash.foreach-4.5.0.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org

160 verbose stack at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)

160 verbose stack at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:203:13)

160 verbose stack at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:402:9)

160 verbose stack at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:203:13)

160 verbose stack at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)

160 verbose stack at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)

160 verbose stack at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
```

Client's Node version is : v12.6.0

Client's NPM version is : 6.9.0

This below screenshot given by client

[image]

How to solve this error without client's Node & NPM upgrade?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the cause of the error 'getaddrinfo EAI\_AGAIN'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182121/whats-the-cause-of-the-error-getaddrinfo-eai-again)

Comment: @Phil Since none of the many answers to to that question have been accepted, what do you suggest OP try?

Comment: @HansKilian why should that matter. The answer seems pretty obvious, OP's clients have issues with their networking