# Getting this error in node.js Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN

Tags: node.js, postgresql, microservices

We're following a microservice architecture and we have internal API calls to get responses from other microservices. We have noticed that one out of five times API is failing with the below error:

error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN - Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26)

Can anybody guide us for the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the cause of the error 'getaddrinfo EAI\_AGAIN'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182121/whats-the-cause-of-the-error-getaddrinfo-eai-again)