# ECONNREFUSED when connecting Firebase Function with Google Cloud SQL MYSQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, firebase, sequelize.js, google-cloud-sql

Here's my config.json from Sequelize:

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "xxxx",
    "database": "xxxx",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "dialectOptions": {
      "socketPath": "/cloudsql/xxx:xxxx:xxxx"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

And I deployed at Firebase Functions with `firebase deploy`.

But when I do something with database, it shows
`SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED /cloudsql/xxx:xxx:xxx`

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible code that provides the error? also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working config:

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize("test-db", "test-user", "mypassword", {
  dialect: "mysql",
  host: "/cloudsql/PROJECT:REGION:INSTANCE",
})
```

Sequalize wants a host that points to the Unix socket.

No other configuration on the Firebase Functions side is necessary.

Comment: But is it possible to connect Firebase Function with Google Cloud SQL?

Comment: Yes. See the docs for Cloud Functions which will be the same for Firebase functions: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions.

Comment: I tried this by remove host, but I still get the same error like Sequelize doesn't want to connect with the socketPath. Is there something I need to setup google cloud SQL so it could connect to entity framework like Sequelize?

Comment: Updated my answer after testing this manually. It's not obvious from the docs, either Cloud SQL or Sequalize.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I got a different error again which is ``SequelizeConnectionError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN /cloudsql/PROJECT:REGION:INSTANCE``

Comment: I already deployed into Firebase Hosting, but I still got that error.

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55132016/927514

Comment: Also I assume you're swapping out PROJECT for your project, REGION for your database's region, and INSTANCE for your Cloud SQL instance's name...