# Getting DNS error when executing js script with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```js
const { Client, EmbedBuilder, GatewayIntentBits, Collection, Events, Partials } = require("discord.js");
require("dotenv").config();
const { Guilds, GuildMembers, GuildMessages } = GatewayIntentBits;
const { User, Message, GuildMember, ThreadMember } = Partials;
const client = new Client({
    intents: [Guilds, GuildMembers, GuildMessages],
    Partials: [User, Message, GuildMember, ThreadMember]
});
client.login(process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN);
```

This is my index.js
When I execute node index.js, it gives me this error:

```js
Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN discord.com
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26) {
  errno: -3001,
  code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'discord.com'
```

I tried to contact my internet provider, and they said they found nothing weird or errors in my modem.
They suggested asking here what I could do.

I tried changing DNS from automatic to google nameservers and vice versa, but it did not work.
Does someone know how to fix this? Its really annoying!

My OS is ChromeOS/Linux

**EXPECTATION:**

I executed **node index.js**, and it should execute the script and put the bot online. I have this issue on my home network & mobile hotspot, not networks like work or school.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the cause of the error 'getaddrinfo EAI\_AGAIN'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182121/whats-the-cause-of-the-error-getaddrinfo-eai-again)

Comment: On your home network and mobile hotspot, _but using the same computer_? In that case, the issue is with your computer. Possibly antivirus software.

Comment: @jabaa I tried that and it didnt work, sadly

Comment: @robertklep there is not like an antivirus that i installed myself. and it works on public wifi connections so idk if that is really the problem

Answer (score 0):

I somehow solved this issue bij removing Linux from my system and reinstalling it.

Answer (score -1):

If you are on windows check your Windows Defender Firewall and make sure that the Node process is allowed to connect to the internet on private networks not only public.
As an alternative to that you could change your connected WiFi/Ethernet to be a public network instead of private network in connection settings.

This is the most likely scenario i can think of as you say it works on public connections.
[image]

Comment: Either answer the question for all common operating systems (Windows, Mac, Linux) or clarify the operating system.

Comment: I did say which OS is in use in the example if you read the first line i stated "If you are on windows"

Comment: Yes, but the OP didn't say they use Windows. If they don't use Windows, this answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: And i stated this answer is only for Windows. I know the OP did not state what OS they use which is why i said the only one i know how to fix off the top of my head. I stated the only OS i know how to fix this issue on since i do not own a mac and have never personally experienced this problem on any Linux distro.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello! I am using ChromeOS/Linux. I am sorry for not clarifying my OS.